# How to show an image file through Angular and Spring boot?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I want to display an image on Angular app through Spring boot REST service. The image file could be anywhere on the disk not necessarily in assets folder. How can I implement this?

Comment: How you are planning to deploy the spring boot application ? In the embedded server or separate server ?

Comment: @Shan.M I am using jar2exe from www.jar2exe.com to convert final jar file to a windows service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set following property under *application.yml* (or properties) to expose static file to outside.After that you can access the file like
**HOST:PORT/IMAGE_NAME.EXTENSION**

```
spring:
  resources:
    static-locations: file:<PATH TO THE FOLDER>
```

Comment: Hi, actually I'm storing (thanks to spring boot) the image in assets in Angular, the problem is when is deployed it doesn't find the path, can help me to solve it how should I move, thanks so mush